# StaticImage extent stretching the map

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to use the georeferenced image as map in OpenLayers, but I have a hard time figuring out all the pieces.

Image is created from OSM, it's basically a big screenshot of OSM map (I assume projection should be EPSG:3857)

To georeference, I'm using Affine function I found on the internet:

```js
let parameters = {};

const transform = function(point) {
  const x = parameters.A * point[0] + parameters.B * point[1] + parameters.C;
  const y = parameters.D * point[0] + parameters.E * point[1] + parameters.F;
  return [x, y];
};
const calculate = function(sourcePoints, targetPoints) {
  const numberPoints = sourcePoints.length;

  if (numberPoints < 3) throw "Number of points must be at least 3!";
  if (sourcePoints.length !== targetPoints.length)
    throw "Number of points do not mach!";

  let i;

  let sp = [];
  for (i = 0; i < numberPoints; i++) {
    sp[i] = sourcePoints[i].slice(0);
  }
  let tp = [];
  for (i = 0; i < numberPoints; i++) {
    tp[i] = targetPoints[i].slice(0);
  }

  i = 0;
  let xcg, ycg, xcl, ycl;
  let a1, b1, a2, b2, c1, c2;

  xcg = ycg = xcl = ycl = a1 = b1 = a2 = b2 = c1 = c2 = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < numberPoints; i++) {
    xcg = xcg + tp[i][0];
    ycg = ycg + tp[i][1];
    xcl = xcl + sp[i][0];
    ycl = ycl + sp[i][1];
  }

  xcg /= numberPoints;
  ycg /= numberPoints;
  xcl /= numberPoints;
  ycl /= numberPoints;
  for (i = 0; i < numberPoints; i++) {
    tp[i][0] -= xcg;
    tp[i][1] -= ycg;
    sp[i][0] -= xcl;
    sp[i][1] -= ycl;
  }
  let x1 = 0;
  let y1 = 0;
  let x2 = 0;
  let y2 = 0;
  let x3 = 0;
  let y3 = 0;
  let x4 = 0;
  let n1 = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < numberPoints; i++) {
    x1 += sp[i][0] * tp[i][0];
    y1 += sp[i][1] * tp[i][0];
    x2 += sp[i][0] * sp[i][0];
    y2 += sp[i][1] * tp[i][1];
    x3 += sp[i][0] * tp[i][1];
    y3 += sp[i][1] * sp[i][1];
    x4 += sp[i][0] * sp[i][1];
  }
  a1 = x1 * y3 - y1 * x4;
  b1 = y1 * x2 - x1 * x4;
  a2 = y2 * x2 - x3 * x4;
  b2 = x3 * y3 - y2 * x4;
  n1 = x2 * y3 - x4 * x4;
  a1 /= n1;
  b1 /= n1;
  a2 /= n1;
  b2 /= n1;
  c1 = xcg - a1 * xcl - b1 * ycl;
  c2 = ycg - a2 * ycl - b2 * xcl;

  parameters.A = a1;
  parameters.B = b1;
  parameters.C = c1;
  parameters.D = b2;
  parameters.E = a2;
  parameters.F = c2;

  return parameters;
};

export { calculate, transform };
```

Image size is 11520x11756px and I build extent with this code:

```js
let image_src = 'map.jpg'
let extent = [
  Affine.transform([0,0])[0],
  Affine.transform([0,0])[1],
  Affine.transform([11520,11776])[0],
  Affine.transform([11520,11776])[1],
]
```

My problem is that with this extent, map coordinates are working somewhat properly (points are close to true position), but map image is stretched on X axis (it's widened). It looks like OSM projected to EPSG:4326 in this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-wgs84.html

When I use image size in pixels as extent (`extent = [0, 0, 11520, 11776]`), map is not stretched, but coordinates are placed on pixels (lonlat [30, 20] would end up on [30, 20] pixel on map)

I'm not sure if this is due to bad Affine function, bad projections or my poor understanding of extents and projections.

Openlayers code:

```js
let image_src = 'map.jpg'
let extent = [
  Affine.transform([0,0])[0],
  Affine.transform([0,0])[1],
  Affine.transform([11520,11776])[0],
  Affine.transform([11520,11776])[1],
]
let imageLayer = new ImageLayer()

imageLayer.setSource(new Static({
  url: image_src,
  projection: "EPSG:3857",
  imageExtent: extent
}))

map.addLayer(imageLayer)

map.setView(new View({
      projection: "EPSG:3857",
      extent: extent
    })
  )
```

Comment: If you know the projection all you would need is to find two pixels, close to opposite corners, which correspond to known features.  Then extrapolate from those coordinates to the corner pixels to get the extent.

Comment: Hey @Mike, that's exactly what I'm doing. I georeferenced map using 3 control points, and used Affine.transform to find corners coordinates, which I'm using as extent. But I don't know why map becomes stretched after this.

Comment: There should be no stretching if your calculated extent width/height ratio equals the image size width/height ratio.  If they are not equal (to plus/minus 1 pixel precision) either your calculation or assumption about the projection is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me some direction. I'll take a look at ratio